# Closing an IDataReader after yield return is complete

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

Actually it doesn't have to be an `IDataReader`.

I had a function something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetObjects() 
{
  IDataReader dr = GetSomeDataReader();
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    yield return new MyClass(dr);
  }
  CloseDBConnections();
}
```

This was working fine until I refactored it like so:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetObjects() 
{
  IDataReader dr = GetSomeDataReader();
  try
  {
    return ProcessReader(dr);
  } finally {
    CloseDBConnections();
  }
}
public IEnumerable<MyClass> ProcessReader(IDataReader dr)
{
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    yield return new MyClass(dr);
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because when the `CloseDBConnections()` is executed the enumeration has not yet been processed.

Calling `.ToList()` on the return from `GetObjects` is what actually executes the enumeration but by then the connection has already been destroyed and the `IDataReader` fails.

In my instance `CloseDBConnections` cannot be called from within the new `ProcessReader` function because the `IDataReader` could have come from some other source (the whole point of re-factoring in this instance)

Is there a sensible workaround for this or will I have to duplicate the enumerating code?

I tried putting the call to `ProcessReader` as `yield return` instead of `return` but this doesn't work because C# (understandably) thinks I am trying to add an `IEnumerable` to the `IEnumerable`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about calling `CloseDBConnections` in `ProcessReader` via a callback?

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetObjects() 
{
  return ProcessReader(GetSomeDataReader(), CloseDBConnections);
}

public IEnumerable<MyClass> ProcessReader(IDataReader dr, Action OnFinished)
{
  try
  {
    while (dr.Read())
      yield return new MyClass(dr);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (OnFinished != null) 
      OnFinished();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should execute the callback in a `finally`. Without that, it won't be executed if the iteration completes early (e.g. `GetObjects().First()`).

Comment: @DominicKexel I like it.
This is much how I end up doing many things in Javascript

Comment: @svick I wasn't aware of this - I guess this means the original code should have a same try/finally for the same reason.

Comment: @DJL Yeah, you're right, the `finally` is necessary there too.

Answer (score 3):

Not pretty, but this should work.

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetObjects() 
{
  IDataReader dr = GetSomeDataReader();
  try
  {
    foreach (var result in ProcessReader(dr))
    {
      yield return result;
    }
  } finally {
    CloseDBConnections();
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah I did consider this.
I was hoping for a cleaner solution (like some magic keyword or something).
In this instance it hardly seems worth the bother of re-factoring if the above solution is the only one possible.

I guess I was probably hoping for too much!